# Joins in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, mapper

while going through the hadoop in action book i came across Several Classes regarding reduced joins,some of them are DataJoinMapperBase,TaggedMapOutput,DataJoinReducerBase.

but when i had gone through google to search for joins concept on hadoop,none them are based on the above specified classes.instead they were implementing their own logics and many are based on MultipleInputs.

Now My question is which is the better approach for joins on hadoop?what could be done to achieve better results?any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: as of now i wanted an innerjoin of two tables

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Pangool](http://pangool.net/userguide/joins.html) library, it makes reduce side joins very easy. Map side joins are just a memory lookup.